# ¿ Como hago para desactivar los inlay hints en vscode?

Tags: java, vscode

lo que sucede es que empezaron a aparecer palabras como text, manager, width, height en mi código de vscode(es molesto, pero a la vez sirve como orientación), si alguien sabe como desactivar esto se los agradecería
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presiona `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`, teclea `open settings json` para  abrir tu archivo de configuración `settings.json`. Agrega la línea:

```
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": false
```

Alternativamente abre `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` y en el buscador coloca "inlayHints". Desmarca la casilla que dice *Enables the inlay hints in the editor*.