# ¿Cómo desactivar anotaciones de parámetros en el código en VSCode?

Tags: vscode, anotaciones

[image]

Quiero que no aparezcan estas anotaciones.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿ Como hago para desactivar los inlay hints en vscode?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/528028/como-hago-para-desactivar-los-inlay-hints-en-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

Con una [búsqueda rápida](https://www.google.com/search?q=code%20disable%20parameter%20name%20hints&tbm=isch) en Google Imágenes pude encontrar [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68720113) para Visual Studio Code y otros IDE también.

En Visual Studio Code esas anotaciones se llaman `Inlay Hints`.

Puedes desactivarlas cambiando la configuración `Editor > Inlay Hints` a `off`.